# wp_nav_menu in 3.7 add name class nav navbar-nav

Tags: menus, customization, themes

i work with bootstrap3 and wordpress 3.6 but upgrade to 3.7 function wp_nav_menu not work correctly.

i use 3.6

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(
    array(
    'container' => false,
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
    'theme_location' => 'menu_principal'
    )); ?>
</nav>
```

but this code no work in 3.7 not add ul class nav navbar-nav. why? thanks.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress2/?page_id=7">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress2/?page_id=9">contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

not add the class ul why?

Comment: What output do you get when you try the code suggested in my answer below?

Comment: Also: are you sure this is the same menu? You're passing `'container' => false`, but the rendered output has `<div class="menu">`, which suggests to me that you're looking at a different `wp_nav_menu()` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

In this case, it appears that the problem is that you're not actually outputting a custom nav menu at all, but rather the **menu fallback: `wp_page_menu()`**. Notice that the classes for the list items are `page-item` rather than `menu-item`. That's a sure giveaway that the output is being generated by `wp_page_menu()` rather than `wp_nav_menu()`.

**Solution**: Ensure that you have created a custom nav menu, and assigned it to the `menu_principal` Theme Location.

### Original Answer

Long answer, short: you're using the correct method to modify `menu_class`, and in the process, likely stepping on c[hanges that were made to `wp_nav_menu()` between WordPress 3.6 and 3.7](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset?sfp_email=&sfph_mail=&reponame=&new=25602@trunk/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php&old=25410@trunk/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php).

Instead of messing with `items_wrap`, you need to be manipulating `menu_class`, which is the correct parameter for defining the class applied to the menu element output by [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu):

> `$menu_class`
>
> *(string) (optional)* The class that is applied to the `ul`
>   element which encloses the menu items. Multiple classes can be
>   separated with spaces. Formerly known as `$wrap_class`.
>
> Default: `menu`

Try this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'theme_location' => 'menu_principal'
) ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but menu_class put in div and i want in ul tag.

Comment: No, the `<div>` is the **container**, the class for which is controlled by `container_class`. The `menu_class` parameter adds the specified class to the **list element `<ul>`**. P.S. please *edit your question* to include **actual code used**, along with the **rendered output**.

Comment: See edited answer. That output is being generated by the fallback `wp_page_menu()`, *not* by `wp_nav_menu()`.